# Determines order in foreach(Panel p in pnl)

Tags: c#, foreach, panel

I have got a panel, called pnl inside of which are for more panels, call them p. Now the user can choose a color for every panel p.

I then want to determine the color of each panel p in panel pnl.

I used a foreach loop which looks like foreach(Panel p in pnl). However I need to know the color of each panel from left to right to stroe them in an int-array. The foreach-loop seems to look at the panels p in always the same order, however I wondered where I can set this order.

Is it by name? (I couldn't find a way to name them so that it worked). Or by anything else? How can I change the order?

I hope my question is clear and look foward to answers

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: by adding controls dynamically to controls array of Main Panel , you control the order (  before add sorting as you want )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to try to enumerate in left to right order then:

```
foreach (Panel p in pnl.Controls.OfType<Panel>().OrderBy(x => x.Left)) {
  // do something with p
}
```

Comment: and just to add - you can further use `.Select(x => x.Color).ToArray()` as OP mentioned he wants to store them in an int arr. I know you know - just a note for OP (makes no sense posting an answer).

Comment: @NSGaga You probably meant `x => x.BackColor` since Panels don't have a Color property by that name.  :-)

Comment: you're right - I totally did not think about any of that :) just a pseudo code - it was a long time since I actually used that.

Comment: Awesome, works! May anyone explain to me what actually happens? I don'T really understand the msdn-article.

Comment: @user1953145 I don't know which article you are talking about, but the code is just enumerating through all of the panels in your `pnl.Controls` collection, and then re-ordering them based on the `Left` property value of each Panel.  The `x` variable represents each panel it finds in the collection.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I've got another thing where I basically want to do the same, but there panels are arranged in a 2x2 square. I'd like to order them so that the top left comes first, then the top right, then the bottom left and finally the bottom right. So basically first OrderBy(x => x.Bottom) and then OrderBy(x => x.Left) .

Can I do that some way? Like sort by two properties?

Comment: @user1953145 `.OrderBy(x => x.Top).ThenBy(x => x.Left)`

Comment: I found out myself: ThenBy is what I have been looking for. Thanks to LarsTech for his extremely helpful answer again.

Comment: Oh, thank you. You posted this while I was still writing I guess, didn't see it.